# How to remove white space between nav and jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Apologies if this is a stupid question! I have read all the questions around this and tried the solutions but I still can't get my white gap to disappear.

I'm learning HTML & CSS through Codecademy and when I copied my code into codepen, a white space appeared between the nav and the jumbotron.

I've tried removing margins but I can't get it to disappear. Thanks in advance.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: #30627E;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.header ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav li {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

.header .main {
  background-color: #E52364;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin: 0;
}

.jumbotron {
  background: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/adoptly/bg.jpg) repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center; 
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #E52364 !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="main">Adoptly</li>
         <li>About</li>
         <li>Animals</li>
         <li>Blog</li>
         <li>Events</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
     

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Meet your new best friend.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the notorious HTML inline-block elements space. Usually you would have to remove actual spaces between HTML tags but it would be easier for you to simply convert your `.header` into a `block` level element:

```
.header {
  ⋮
  display: block;
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/mpxnu8og/

Comment: Thanks so much for that! I actually managed to get rid of it by adding a negative top-margin value to the Jumbotron. It took me a long time to get there though.

Comment: @haleighlv I wouldn't recommend using negative margin as that could create issues later. Also you would need to apply a negative margin to any container after `.header` if the jumbotron wasn't present.